# How to take screenshot of a URL from a web form in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, webpage-screenshot

Is there a way to do this without any exe files or 3rd party things? I cannot use windows form components in web application and I am in need of taking screenshots of different URLs programmatically. Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: of course not :D i mean web page but not current one

Comment: Then I am confused. Do you mean a rendered webpage at that URL? Using which renderer? Here is what this page looks like in w3m: http://imgur.com/PXm5f , for instance.

Comment: I just need a simple thumbnail like how we see in browser :) like this one: http://beta.thumbalizr.com/app/thumbs/?src=/thumbs/onl/source/e8/e847d6948f57c012bea2d7eedbdb6914.png&w=150&q=0&enc=

Comment: Ahh, so you require a thumbnail of an external web page?  What's wrong with the thumbalizr API you mention?  e.g. http://api.thumbalizr.com/?url=http://www.ford.de&width=250 gives you the thumbnail for http://www.ford.de .

Answer (score 1):

Similar question here: [Using HTML5/Canvas/JavaScript to take screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots)

> JavaScript can read the DOM and render a fairly accurate
>   representation of that using canvas. I [@Niklas] have been working on a script
>   which converts html into an canvas image.

See also: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

**Edit:**

Note: You will need to write a web service/web method that accepts a base64 encoded string as an input parameter, and then saves that string (in its raw form, or converted to a file.)

Example usage of html2canvas:

```
var imageAsBase64;

$('body').html2canvas({
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        imageAsBase64 = canvas.toDataURL();

        // You now have a base64 string, representing a "screenshot" of 
        // your <body> element, which you can POST to your web service.

  }
});
```

Comment: Wouldnt it cause a security problem? Because I also need to save the image.